# How to circumvent the .NET 6 SPA proxy for Angular applications?

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio, iis

Edit: I managed to get this running through IIS with valid certificates, but I've not found a way to ditch the new proxy approach. Skip to end if you want some info on using IIS rather than IIS Express.

In short: Using the latest ASP.NET 6 and Angular template (Visual Studio 2022), how do you go about bypassing the reverse proxy and instead use the same approach as pervious version of .NET? I don't want to run the application via the SPA URL, with backend requests being forwarded to the SPA proxy.

To detail, my goal:

- No IIS Express
- Manually start the Angular Server via a terminal.
- Configure the ASP.NET application to connect to the Angular server, rather than spinning up its own instance,
- Have the the ASP.NET application run from a local instance of IIS 10, with a self signed certificate.
- Attach the debugger to w3wp as required.

I'd like to navigate to https://mydomain.local and have it serve everything, which was no issue prior to .NET 6. You'd use `UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer`, run `npm start` and all was good.

Although I'm aware you can still use it, .NET 6 ditches `Startup.cs`, and guidelines suggest to use the streamlined `Program.cs` going forward.

I have tried:

- Getting rid of the prestart script (`aspnetcore-https.js`)
- Getting rid of the proxy configuration (`proxy.conf.js`) by removing the proxyConfig property from `angular.json`
- Creating an IIS Launch profile and using provisioning
- Changing the SPA configuration values within the .csproj file.
- Getting rid of the --ssl flags (ssl, ssl-cert and ssl-key) in package.json
- Defining a non default host in `angular.json`
- Combinations of the aforementioned

Nothing seems to appears to work, the documentation isn't too great either.

At the moment:

- I have a working self signed certificate (created with mkcert)
- My domain is setup in the hosts file
- The  application setup within IIS and I can load it, with a valid certificate.
- Upon loading, it looks for the valued defined by the `SpaProxyServerUrl` property in the csproj file
- The redirects to https://locaolhost:xxxxx once Angular is running, but the cert if never valid, and I want the pages to be served from https://mydomain.local

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

I am not sure what was wrong with the self signed ASP.NET certificate. I simply removed all references of it and added them again.

- Remove certificates from `%AppData%\Roaming\ASP.NET\https`
- Clear SSL Cache via Internet Options (run command: `inetcpl.cpl`)
- Clear any security policies for the domain via `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`
- Clear down Chrome history (site settings, cached data etc. `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData`)
- Remove certificates from Windows Certificate Store (run command: `mmc` File --> Add/Remove Snap-In --> Certificates). Remove the personal certificate and the trusted root certificate
- Generate the certificates again, either via building the project in VS or running `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`

To ditch IIS Express and reply on a normal IIS Instance:

- Add your application as normal to IIS.
- Create a https binding, I suggest using `mkcert` to create a valid self signed certificate.
- Ensure the https port matches that defined in `launchSettings.json`
- Update `launchSettings.json`, feel free to remove any profiles you don't need. You want something akin to this:

```json
{
    "iisSettings": {
        "windowsAuthentication": false,
        "anonymousAuthentication": true,
        "iis": {
            "applicationUrl": "https://yourdomain.local",
            "sslPort": 443
        }
    },
    "profiles": {
        "IIS": {
            "commandName": "IIS",
            "launchBrowser": true,
            "launchUrl": "https://yourdomain.local",
            "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
                "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Add a new proxy-conf file (I called my proxy-iis.conf) to your ClientApp folder, or update the existing one. If you create a new one, ensure you update `angular.json` to reference it accordingly.

```js
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
    {
        context: [
            "/yourRoute",
        ],
        target: "https://yourdomain.local:443",
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
        logLevel: "info",
        headers: {
            Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
        }
    }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

- Check your `.csproj` file and ensure the port defined within `<SpaProxyServerUrl></SpaProxyServerUrl>` matches the one used `angular.json`

That's it, you'll be good to go. Start the Angular application manually, visit `https://yourdomain.local` and everything should be savvy.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Thanks @samwu. I think I overcomplicated my question. I've edited and added a short / simplified version.

Comment: Should your update section be moved to an answer?

Comment: If you want to keep the new ASP.NET Core 6 approch, but allow passthrough URLs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72492121/asp-net-core-6-angular-rest-prefix-using-microsoft-aspnetcore-spaproxy

Comment: Answers go in the Answers section, not as part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

What I did  so I can start Angular manually and don't need a restart on each server side change, was to add the following to my package.json.

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
       "dev": "set ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=7186 && npm start"
     }  
    ...
}
```

Change the `7186` to the port that the .Net 6 server is running on (in your case 443). Then run "npm run dev", wait for it to load and start the backend server.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this issue when running a Angular .Net project on linux and I fixed this for our project, I imagine it's the same issues when running IIS.

#### How requests were handled before

```
Browser -> Angular dev server tries serving -> Rest to .Net server
```

Run the dev server straight from angular, no proxy, no nothing. The pros are that it just works, cons are that image/jpeg and text/html requests don't go through .Net middleware.

#### Now

Starting SPA via .Net

```
Browser -> .Net server -> proxy-conf.js -> Angular dev server or .Net based on conf
```

or if you run project locally

```
Browser -> Angular dev server -> proxy-conf.js -> .Net server
```

#### Prod stays the same

```
Browser -> .Net server handles -> Server static files if needed
```

#### Changes in behavior with default

- Requests need to be on a whitelist to go to .net server
- Requests run options requests before
- Requests are redirected without the followRedirects enabled by default
- Redirected requests don't contain same headers (like Authorization)

#### What worked for me

```
// proxy-conf.js
const { env } = require('process');

// replace 44373 with your .Net server https port. If not using SSL then you could use the http port I think.
const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
  env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'https://localhost:44373';

const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      // Add the urls you want to go to the server, double star is nice
      // "/api/*" matches "/api/controller" and 
      // "/api/**" matches "/api/controller/some/method/id"
      "/images/**",
      "/files/**",
      "/api/**"
   ],
    target: target,
    // This defaults to false, but absolutely needed to have the same behavior
    // as running the SPA through the .Net server.
    followRedirects: true,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```